# BMI Calculation Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

BMI = [weight(kg)]/ [height(m)]
(*Formula given)

```
import UIKit

class BMIViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtHeight: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtWeight: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lblOutput: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func btnCalculateBMI(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let  height = Double(txtHeight.text!)
        let weight = Double(txtWeight.text!)
        
        let bmi = weight! / (height! * height!)
         
        
        lblOutput.text = String(bmi)
    }
}
```

When running the application, there was too much decimals. How am I able to fix this issue?enter image description here

Comment: When presenting numbers to users, always use `NumberFormatter`. The same is valid when parsing numeric input from the user.

Comment: Force unwrapping the text to number conversion when dealing with user input is not a good approach. You are assuming the user is going to enter numbers only. You might have set up a numeric keypad to only allow numbers, but that doesn't help if the user uses copy-paste to insert whatever they like.